# Geometric interpretation of the coefficients of the quadratic equation.

Tags: quadratics

The quadratic equation has three general forms:

> 1. $ax^2+bx+c$
> 2. $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$
> 3. $a(x-h)^2+k$

- $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the zeroes of the quadratic.
- $h$ is the horizontal position of the vertex, $k$ is the vertical position of the vertex.

Are there any such geometric interpretations the coefficients, $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Comment: $c$ is the $y$-intercept.  $a$ is the shape parameter.  $b$ as it stands doesn't have much of an intuitive interpretation, but $b/2a$ is the axis of symmetry.  Changes in $b$ translate the parabola.

Comment: $b$ is the slope of the tangent at the $y$-intercept.

Comment: Enzotib.  That's a really good point.  Never thought of that.  I always think of the sign of a as determining if the parabola points up and down.  The size of a determines how wide or narrow the parabola is, but the is no really units of measure. Theoretically as f(x) = a^2 +bx + c then f''(x) = a, we can consider a to be an "acceleration constant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figure shows how these quantities are related.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show how $a$ and $b$ are interpreted, only $\frac{b}{a}$. And technically $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Comment: @FrankVel 1) WLOG, we can assume $\alpha \lt \beta$ and the theory applies equally well for the reversed case. 2) Assuming $a \gt 0$ (means the curve is concaved upward) is just one of the  many sub-cases to be discussed . I think the post has served the illustration already and you need to explore other cases yourself.